# Repeat script over and over

Tags: shell, powershell

I wrote a PowerShell script for addition which works but then it closes.

I want to repeat the process over and over.

```
Write-Host ENTER NUMBERS
[INT]$NUM = READ-HOST ENTER NUMBER1
[INT]$NUM = READ-HOST ENTER NUMBER1
$RESULT = $NUM1 + $NUM2
$RESULT
```

After this I want PowerShell to return to the starting. What should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your code into a `while($true)`. You also have to assign the two `Read-Host` return values to `$NUM1` and `$NUM2`:

```
 while($true)
 {
     Write-Host ENTER NUMBERS
    [INT]$NUM1 = READ-HOST ENTER NUMBER1
    [INT]$NUM2 = READ-HOST ENTER NUMBER1
    $RESULT = $NUM1 + $NUM2
    $RESULT
}
```

Comment: @Kiran It is an endless loop but isn't that exactly what John is looking for?